# Controlling EMACS Org-Mode directory choices

Tags: windows, emacs, directory, org-mode

I use Emacs 26.3 and Windows 10 and a very current version of org-mode. In the following discussion "xxxx" is my name for directory naming purposes.

I've been slowly cleaning up my custom-init.el file. I had been specifying the file name/location explicitly and wanted to make things more generic by using a relative name.

I have these lines early in the init file:

```
(setq org-directory "C:/Users/xxxx/Dropbox/emacs/Org/")
(setq org-agenda-files (list org-directory))
```

This results in the loading of the correct agenda files.

A bit latter I have the following code at the beginning of a section that sets up the appearance of emacs org-mode at start-up:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/todo.org")
...
```

In the past I had specified the todo file with an explicit path which worked fine.  But in the clean-up effort I had expected the "~/todo.org" to result in it being concatenated to org-directory, which was naive of me apparently.  Instead, while the todo file is loaded as an agenda file, a new file is created in the Windows root file "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming" and it is this new file that is used for other operations (captures with the templates specifying ~/todo.org).

I've tried for several days to research the problem on-line, but there is just too much information for me to sort through.  Setting the default-directory clearly is buffer specific and C-x C-f gives me a different result as I move from buffer to buffer.

I do want to solve this problem in my custom init file without specifying explicitly the path to each of the files I  refer to in the init file.  What am I not understanding/overlooking?

Comment: If you just want it relative to your `org-directory`, use `(expand-file-name "todo.org" org-directory)`

Comment: Hi again pickle.  You are a good teacher.  That solved most of the problems, but did not work by itself for the capture templates.  Inside of the templates, instead of (file+headline expand-file-name "todo.org" org-directory) "Inbox") or whatever,  it was necessary to either use either lamda () (the expansion...) or to setq org-default-todo-file (the expansion...) and then use the org-default-todo-file variable in the template.  If you repost your comment as an answer I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @picklerick's answer is spot-on for the problem you stated in your question. For the capture template problem in your comment, the `file+headline` method wants two things in order to specify where the capture will go: a pathname to the file and a node headline. In your case, you want the pathname to be specified partly by using a variable (the directory where your agenda org files live).  The standard way of dealing with this problem is the `backquote` mechanism. Here is a ref: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44044/concat-in-org-easy-templates

Comment: @NickD I can see how the backquote syntax works, but I'm pretty green about lisp and if I come back in a few years after I have finished this clean-up, I think that using a variable that I have defined at the start of my capture template section is going to be much more readable for me.  That was also a reason why I didn't use lamda () (the expansion...) since I could see myself coming back much later and wondering why I had tried to be so "clever" having forgotten all about the why.  The problem about the DATE that is explained in the link is another thing for me to try to remember. Thanks!